# Gimp crashes on JPEG save

Tags: zlib

Sometimes different applications crash, and the system notifies me that the crashed application uses a third party library (`libz`) and suggests trying without it.

I can always reproduce it by exporting PNG file to JPEG format in Gimp:

[image]

([Full size screenshot](http://i45.tinypic.com/b8k11.png))

When I first experienced the issue I had libz 1.2.5 installed in the system, then I updated it to 1.2.7, but the issue persists.

I don't know when and what this library was installed for.

===========UPDATE 7.04.2013===========

After looking into strace output I don't think that my issue is related to zlib. So I'm changing the question title

Here is **strace gimp** output (launcher icons size = 36, "Radiance" Gnome theme)

```
futex(0x15b3434, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x15b3430, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0x15b0fb0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x1c4a560, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
lstat("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/share/icons/Humanity/devices/16/drive-harddisk.svg", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7338, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/share/icons/Humanity/devices/16/drive-harddisk.svg", O_RDONLY) = 19
fstat(19, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7338, ...}) = 0
read(19, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UT"..., 65536) = 7338
read(19, "", 65536)                     = 0
close(19)                               = 0
write(2, "\n(gimp:19027): Gtk-CRITICAL **: "..., 106
(gimp:19027): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_tree_model_get: assertion `GTK_IS_TREE_MODEL (tree_model)' failed
) = 106
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---

(script-fu:19034): LibGimpBase-WARNING **: script-fu: gimp_wire_read(): error
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried reinstalling the packages, but that didn't help.

```
$ file /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.7
/usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.7: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0x4b579c2bcc6eb41c0dc9c473e8298e5249fedbe1, not stripped
$ md5sum /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.7
65ffc4f5f7b943cd569ba2136cd49f7b  /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.7
$ ls -lh /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 99K лют  9 19:54 /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.7
```

System: Ubuntu 12.04 x64_86
Gimp 2.6.12

Comment: Usually libs are installed in `/usr/lib{32}` and not in `/usr/local/lib`. Didn't you installed it manually? If you don't need a specific recent version, there is available on the repos an older version of zlib (v1.2.3.4).

Comment: You are right Salem. I mentioned in the description that I installed this library for some reason I can't remember, probably attempting to solve this issue. I've removed /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1 symlink and as per strace right library (1.2.3.4) is used now by Gimp. Unfortunately that didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question by myself.

I think that at the beginning my question was little misleading.

The system reported me that the crash could happen because of third party library used by Gimp (/usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.7).

I removed /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1 symlink to /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.7 and traced with strace that default library is used

```
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff82fc2f00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7fff82fc2f00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7fff82fc2f00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P \0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=92720, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2187824, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f99b8b30000
mprotect(0x7f99b8b46000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f99b8d45000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x7f99b8d45000
close(3)
```

That didn't fix the issue.

But after some additional research I think I've found [related bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp/+bug/912909).